# How to increment a cell by one, depending on a criteria and when the year changes?

Tags: excel

I'm trying to formulate row Y such that it starts counting from 1 when row X is 1, and increment by 1 throughout the year when it is a new year. So for example table 1 shows when column X = 1 in the last month of the year, and begins a new year after that, where there will be an increment in row Y just ONCE, until there is a new year again.

I'm looking to formulate cell Y so that when i copy paste the same formula for table 2 (i have a total of 6 tables with different starting years), it should work the same.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With ***Microsoft Excel 365*** you can try below formula-

```
=IF(B3<>0,XMATCH(B2,UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(FILTER($B$2:$M$2,$B$3:$M$3<>0))),0),0)
```

Drag the formula to right as you needed.

[image]